# Mysql duvida em fk null (Eleição candidato em branco)

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Estou fazendo um sistema de votação e preciso que aceite votos em branco
qual a melhor opção para fazer isso? aceitar passar um valor null na coluna cd_candidato?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

não posso criar um candidato em branco na tabela candidato

motivo: vão ter muita categoria e cada categoria vai ter a opção branco
o sistema pega os candidatos da categoria escolhida pelo eleitor

eu poderia fazer uma tabela votos em branco e alimentar ela no lugar do tb_votos mas isso mudaria tudo na contagem de votos por categoria.